# error: expected `;' before ':' token

Tags: c++

This error is from the first line, **peer : m_peerList**

I don't know how to solve this, I tried everything.

```
const char * peer;
for (peer : m_peerList)
{
    if (peer->IsAuth() || !peer->IsValid() || peer->GetChannel() != p->channel) //not the channel we are looking for!
        continue;

    TMapLocation kMapLocation;
    thecore_memcpy(kMapLocation.alMaps, peer->GetMaps(), sizeof(kMapLocation.alMaps));

    for (const auto midx :: kMapLocation.alMaps)
    {
        if (midx == p->lMapIndex)
        {
            //Get host, and convert to int
            char host[16];
            strlcpy(host, peer->GetPublicIP(), sizeof(kMapLocation.szHost));
            lAddr = inet_addr(host);

            //Target port
            port = peer->GetListenPort();

            break;
        }
    }

    if (lAddr && port) //We already obtained them
        break;
}
```

Error:

```
error: expected `;' before ':' token
```

If you can help me, I would be so much thank to you.

Comment: `for (const char* peer : m_peerList)`

Comment: `for (auto& peer: m_peerList)`   Maybe add a `const` after `auto`

Answer (score 2):

It must be compiled with the flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` . Also look at the second for-loop, it has an error.

Comment: In case you are wondering what the *error* is you are using the `::` scope resolution operator instead of  `:` in the modern for loop syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo

```
for (const auto midx :: kMapLocation.alMaps)
```

should be

```
  for (const auto midx : kMapLocation.alMaps).
```